# Coding for Image manipulation using touch screen

Tags: image, touchscreen

I would like to program an application that will:

- Display an image (jpeg, hd, 1920 x 1080 px) on a touchscreen.
- When the user touch the screen and displaces his/her finger, the image will replace the pixels of the "touched" zone for pixels coming from another image.

I heard somebody talking about "unity" (2D? 3D?) that would be able of doing that.
Then I saw that there's an SDL_2 package capable of taking into account a touch screen device.

--> Would you some of you please advice me about this? Which developing system may be the best for what I'm looking for? And which language do you think may be the most suited? The system I'm looking for has to be very fast when treating the image, in order to give a "fluid" behaviour.

Sorry for this beginner's question, but as I now it will be a really hard work for me in order to figure out how to implement it, at least I would like to start from the best starting point.

Thank you very much, I really look forward to have any advice about this.

Best Regards,

P.cordo

Answer (score 0):

something like this can very easily be achieved in Unity3D. From the requirement of it it seems like that it is going to be 2D application.

Just for logic it seems fairly easy to implement. Display the image (PNG/JPG) to full screen size take the input touchdown and find out the pixels co-ordinate. Once you have the co-ordinate set the alpha value for those pixels to be 0. In this case you may want to use size factor to cause remove single pixel may not even be visible in general case.

For the overlaying effect, you may consider using Unity UI and maintain proper Z-order for images and do raycasting to select image for removing the pixels.

For reference I have attached a script as well, check it out:

```
public class ImageUpdate : MonoBehaviour {

    public Texture2D tex;
    public int size = 25;

    Color32[] texPix;
    int width,height;


    void Start()
    {
        //Initialising image components
        GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = tex;
        width = tex.width;
        height = tex.height;
        texPix = tex.GetPixels32 ();
        tex = new Texture2D (width, height, TextureFormat.ARGB32,false);
        tex.SetPixels32 (texPix);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Update this to touch for mobile devices
        if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
            Vector2 pixelPos = Input.mousePosition;

            //Removing the touched pixels
            for(int i=-size;i<size;i++)
                for(int j=-size;j<size;j++)
                    tex.SetPixel ((int)Mathf.Clamp(i + pixelPos.x,0,width), (int)Mathf.Clamp(j + (int)pixelPos.y,0,height), new Color (0, 0, 0, 0));

            UpdateImage ();
        }
    }

    void UpdateImage()
    {
        //tex = new Texture2D (width, height, TextureFormat.ARGB32,false);
        //tex.SetPixels32 (texPix);
        //Applying the updates
        tex.Apply ();
        GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = tex;
    }
}
```

Now the only thing you need to keep in mind is the mapping of image resolution to your screen resolution. If the image is not same as your screen resolution, in that case you can use offset values to adjust for gap.

Comment: Shubhamrock828 thank you very much for your answer!!! You also send me a code to start with, that's really awesome: thank you very much!

Comment: @P.cordo
If it addresses your problem then please mark this as an answer.